# Functioning of a reset circuit for a microcontroller (PIC)

Tags: capacitor, switches, pic

Following microchip data sheet I have created a reset circuit (MCLR) that looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fod9Ix.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have several questions surrounding this:

- When I press the button, will the capacitor discharge?
- The data sheet claims that that the diode helps the capacitor discharge faster, but how, if there is no resistor to unload it?
- Why there is a need for a capacitor?

Comment: Do you really need such a big capacitor? Such a big capacitor will eventually "destroy" the switch. As for your questions. Q1) Yes. Q2) - via the PIC or any additional load content between Vcc and GND.

Comment: Can you supply a link to the datasheet for this device? Most modern versions have extensive internal filtering and protection circuitry on the reset line, as well as power on and brownout features that make such circuitry unnecessary.

Comment: @PStechPaul https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39689b.pdf

Comment: Q3) R1 and C1 form a low-pass RC filter. It essentially applies a delay to the MCLR signal.

Comment: That is a preliminary version of the datasheet from 2006, and the reset circuit shown in figure 4-2 (for slow start-up power supply) does not show the same components as what you show in your post. It also does not show a reset switch.

Comment: you say `diode helps the capacitor discharge faster` ... the datasheet says `The diode D helps discharge the capacitor quickly when VDD powers down` ... you left out the part about the discharge path

Comment: @glen_geek: It will prevent the left node of R2 from rising above Vdd+diode drop.  The resistance of R2 is large enough that the right node can rise to e.g. 12V with a tolerable current.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're right (comment deleted). "Tolerable current" is not often specified in programmer's Vpp generator - I hope it can drive that 4k resistor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I press the button, will the capacitor discharge?

Yes. The switch is directly across the capacitor. When you close the switch, it shorts across the capacitor and discharges it.

> the diode helps [the] capacitor discharge faster, but how if there is no resistor to unload it?

There is a load (though not exactly a resistor). There are two, as a matter of fact:

1. The rest of the circuit connected to the power supply
2. The circuit inside the microcontroller

When the power goes away, current flows from capacitor C1, through D1, through all the ICs connected to the power supply, to ground, and back into C1. Less current also flows from capacitor C1, through R2, into the reset pin of the microcontroller, to the upper protection diode inside the microcontroller, through the circuits inside the microcontroller, to ground, and back into C1.

Comment: I think if I were going to use a great big capacitance like that I'd insert a low-value resistor inbetween the MCLR line and the switch-diode junction, to limit the current.  Probably 10 ohms or less, but depending on the switch's current rating.

Comment: @Davide Andrea, can you elaborate on why is the case for question 1) ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't know how a switch works?  Or maybe a capacitor?  A closed switch is a short circuit, with essentially no resistance.  A capacitor with its terminals shorted is discharged.  A _perfect_ switch would discharge a perfect capacitor instantaneously; with real components it just takes very very little time.

Comment: I've done reset circuits like this long ago with microprocessors.  I see no purpose to D1 because, unless there was some kinda spike coming from some source I don't see, there is no reason for any appreciable current to flow through it.  It simply clamps the voltage going in to be no more than 0.6v above VCC, which seems to me to be a safety measure.   I suppose when you turn the box off and VCC goes to 0, the cap will discharge without the switch button being pushed.  That might keep the processor safe from a forward bias to the substrate which might hurt things.  Okay, I get why D1 is there.

Comment: @Charles34 See my edit.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson _. I see no purpose to D1_ That's because you neglected to consider what happens when the power goes away for 100 ms. If so, we want to reset the microcontroller. Without D1, when the power returns, C1 is still charged, so there is no reset. With D1, the capacitor is quickly discharged through D1 and the components across the power supply and, when the power returns, the discharged capacitor resets the microcontroller.

Comment: @DavideAndrea: D1 is not there to cause a reset if the power glitches, the brown-out detector in the MCU will do that.  It's to prevent latchup by applying a voltage to an MCU that's unpowered.

Comment: @Ben Voigt That IS the purpose of the diode. OP's circuit was developed back when microcontrollers did not include a brown-out detector. Back then, the diode was added for the specific purpose of discharging the capacitor rapidly. What protects the microcontroller's input is not D1, it's R2. (Old enough to remember.)

Comment: @DavideAndrea: OP's circuit includes a button for the user to press.  It's still perfectly applicable to modern MCUs with brown-out detection.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the switch shorts the cap to ground, discharging it.  As noted, this may be bad for the switch -- I'd probably put a low-value resistor in there to limit current (divide VCC by the switch's current rating to get the resistor value -- if it's too high then either tell yourself you can go with more current because it's not for very long, use a different switch, or don't use such a high capacitance).

The diode does -- essentially -- nothing in normal operation.  What it does is prevent the MCLR line's voltage from being more than a diode drop above VCC.  This situation would be bad in the interval where the board is powering down (check your chip's absolute maximum ratings -- it should have something in there about not letting input pins exceed VCC by some amount).

If I used that circuit, I'd consider using a Schottky diode there, to better control the MCLR voltage.

Comment: the way the cap discharges is through the switch button, that's why you suggest placing a resistor in between to smooth the current that the button is going to consume when the cap is discharged?

Comment: Not to smooth so much as to limit, but yes.  With a big enough cap and a small enough switch, you'll degrade the switch contacts each time you push it -- \$4.7\mu\mathrm F\$ is big enough to do serious damage to a little PC-mount switch, even after a dozen presses or so.

Comment: @TimeWescott, probably more problems with capacitors, because now I am wondering what is the use of this capacitor in this setting

Comment: @Charles34 i think the purpose of the cap is to hold the reset line low at the time of power up.  So the chip comes up and gets its act together, internally, ***before*** the reset pin goes high.  Then the chip is properly booted upon power up.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: that, and to make sure the reset pulse stays low long enough to do some good.  Most microprocessors have some required minimum width of the reset pulse.

Comment: Tim, what would be typical values for the cap and for R1?

Comment: It depends mostly on the chip, and to some extent on the circuit designer.  Unless the chip has a well-defined Schmitt-trigger input I would use a reset manager in lieu of this circuit.  Or if it was a manufacturer I trusted I'd just copy their recommended reset circuit -- resets can be tricky.

Answer (score 3):

1. R1-C1 integrating network produces low voltage pulse of sufficient duration when the power is turned on ("automatic reset").
2. D1 provides a discharging path for C1 through the rest of circuit to ground when the power is turned off. Thus the reset circuit is immediately prepared for the next power up.
3. SW1, when pressed, provides low voltage connecting the microcontroller's input to ground ("manual reset"). IMO there is no need to discharge the capacitor since the time for which a person keeps the button pressed is quite enough for the controller to perform the reset function. So the switch can be connected directly between the microcontroller's input and ground (after R2). Contact bounce can be the only problem; so it should be experimented.

The network of diode D1 and resistor R1 in parallel can be considered as a "non-linear resistor" - when the power is "on", its resistance is R1; when the power is "off", its resistance is almost zero. As a result, the capacitor C1 is slowly charged during power up and quickly discharged when the power goes out.